# Which two football clubs are competing in this YouTube video billed as the first ever filmed football match in 1897?

Tags: football, history

Footage from the first filmed football match in 1897 can be found on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNW-h4WbuNU).

I was just wondering, who are the two football clubs in action?

Comment: The [IMDB entry for the short](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0350952/) notes the filming location as "London, England". Rules it down a little bit, but not much.

Answer (score 10):

According the [The Belfast Telegraph](https://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/northern-ireland/newly-colourised-footage-brings-1897-belfast-football-match-back-to-life-41054942.html), this is a match between [Glentoran FC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glentoran_F.C.) and [Cliftonville FC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliftonville_F.C.) on Mersey Street in Belfast, Northern Ireland, and is indeed thought to be the first known video of a football match:

> Archive footage of a football match in east Belfast dating back to 1897 has been brought to life with a stunning new colourised version appearing online.
>
> The footage of Glentoran v Cliftonville was taken in Mersey Street and is thought to be the oldest available in the world of any football match.
>
> It was captured by Frenchman Alexandre Promio for the Lumiere Brothers company at the time and later screened at the Belfast Empire to amazed crowds.

From the article - there is now even a colourised, speed-corrected version:

Comment: So, the filming location being listed as London is in error then?  Wonder where they got that idea from?  Stranger still is the country of origin is listed as "France"...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - The "France" is easy to explain in that the Lumière brothers were French...

Comment: I am just looking at that skyline. Just to the right of the skyscrapers (tall buildings) in the horizon, is that a crane I can see? If so, that is likely Belfast docks, and that crane could well be the crane that built the Titanic. If so, then, wow!! I will likely accept this answer shortly. Just going to give it a bit more time.